# Excel 2013 keeps removing commas from CSV at save

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, csv

I'm working with data exports in CSV format. Excel originally opens the files correctly. However, I've been merging in some missing data that my original queries missed (adding four rows of additional data in most cases).

When I save the file (Ctrl+S) the file saves without error.

However, if I close and reopen the file, all the data displays in one column. If you then open the file in a text editor (Notepad, Notepad++, etc), the separating commas have been removed.

This is easy enough to fix, but annoying as all get-out. Anyone know what I have to change in Excel to correct this error?

Side note: I've done this same sort of editing of CSVs with Excel in '07 and '10 without issue. Seems to either be 2013, or possibly (though less likely) an issue injected by how IT at my new employer has setup/installed Office.

Comment: Are the commas just _removed_, or replaced by another character (space, tab, etc.)?

Comment: They appear to be getting replaced by tabs, but I haven't checked the character code to be sure that's the correct character. There's definitely something there though

Comment: Have you checked your regional settings?

Comment: No, but I wasn't aware regional settings would impact this, especially since much of the data is non-numeric. What setting would I need to look at?

Comment: Depends on your operating system..